# Bad: Why typescript Date type not work properly?

Tags: javascript, date

[image]

How to create Date with 1 december 2018? :))) Why this not work? :(

Comment: Read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Month index is zero-based, so December is 11: `new Date(2018, 11, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Month index is from 0 to 11.

```
new Date(2018,11,01)
```